# Call dynamic webservice with session

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have webservice, provide to user. User must login to use it.
My problem is when user login through WSLogin on webservice, I want to save session to check for a next time.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string WSLogin(string username, string password)
{
    // do something
    string sID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Session.Add("SID", sID); // save session
    return sID; // return to user to check next time
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string CallSomethingService(string sID)
{
    string curSID = Session["SID"].ToString() // error, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    // do some thing
}
```

I call webservice dynamically.
Thank for all help

Comment: Can you please use Context.Session instead of Session?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
Session.Add("SID", sID);
```

use this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["SID"] = sSid;
```

And instead of this:

```
string curSID = Session["SID"].ToString();
```

use this:

```
string curSID =  HttpContext.Current.Session["SID"] as string;
```

And make sure you have this in your using statements:

```
using System.Web.SessionState;
```

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Session["SID"] as string
always return null and I don't know System.Web.SessionState use for what methods?

Comment: Then the problem must be when you set the value in the session at this line: string curSID = Session["SID"].ToString(); Can you check and see if you have consistent values (sID, sSid, SID...) And also put a watch on HttpContext.Current to see if there's something there. The line using System.Web.SessionState; must be at the top of the class library.

Comment: When "WSLogin" is called, I create Session["SID"] with one value, next time I called "CallSomethingService", I check value of Session["SID"] but Session["SID"] is not exist. I put a watch on HttpContext.Current to see but in "CallSomethingService" HttpContext.Current.Session.Count always = 0

Comment: There might be a problem with the browser: if it has cookies disabled then when the page is posted back to the server, it has no way of knowing there's a session because the cookie didn't transfer. That might be one of the reason. Did you make the 3 changes I suggested?